# Liquibase error in Quarkus when using with Open telemetry

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, quarkus, open-telemetry

I am try to use OpenTelemetry with quarkus application.

Before use open telemetry It was working file.

this is my application.properties file

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb
quarkus.datasource.password=ddihdh
quarkus.datasource.username=sampledb
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost/sampledb
quarkus.liquibase.change-log=db/changeLog.xml
quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.liquibase.default-schema-name=public
quarkus.application.name=sample-service
quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true 
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://localhost:4317
```

and this is my LiquibaseRunner file

```
package .......;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

import io.quarkus.runtime.LaunchMode;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import io.quarkus.runtime.util.ExceptionUtil;
import liquibase.Contexts;
import liquibase.LabelExpression;
import liquibase.Liquibase;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory;
import liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.ResourceAccessor;
import io.quarkus.logging.Log;

@ApplicationScoped
public class LiquibaseRunner {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url")
    String datasourceUrl;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.username")
    String datasourceUsername;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password")
    String datasourcePassword;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.liquibase.change-log")
    String changeLogLocation;

    public void onApplicationStart(@Observes StartupEvent even) {
        LaunchMode mode = io.quarkus.runtime.LaunchMode.current();
        if(mode != LaunchMode.TEST) {
            this.runMigration();
        } else {
            Log.info("Skipping DB migrations in TEST mode.");
        }
    }
    public void runMigration() {
        Log.info("Migrating DB " + datasourceUrl);
        Liquibase liquibase = null;
        try {
            ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
            DatabaseConnection conn = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().openConnection(datasourceUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword, null, resourceAccessor);
            
            liquibase = new Liquibase(changeLogLocation, resourceAccessor, conn);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("Liquibase Migration Exception: " + ExceptionUtil.generateStackTrace(e));
        }
        finally {
            if(liquibase!=null)
            {
                try {
                    liquibase.close();
                } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
                    Log.info(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
     
}
```

this is working file. But when I try to use with Open telemetry show this error.

application.properties

```
#quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb

## with distributed tracing with OpenTelemetry
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:otel:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.jdbc.OpenTelemetryDriver
```

this is the error

```
2023-02-17 13:20:29,593 INFO  [....inf.dat.LiquibaseRunner] [runMigration] (Quarkus Main Thread) Migrating DB jdbc:otel:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb
2023-02-17 13:20:29,595 ERROR [...inf.dat.LiquibaseRunner] [runMigration] (Quarkus Main Thread) Liquibase Migration Exception: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (jdbc:otel:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:217)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:176)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:159)
    at ....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner.runMigration(LiquibaseRunner.java:49)
    at ....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner_Subclass.runMigration$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at ....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:53)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at .....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner_Subclass.runMigration(Unknown Source)
    at ....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner.onApplicationStart(LiquibaseRunner.java:39)
    at .....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner_Subclass.onApplicationStart$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at .....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:53)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at ....infrastructure.data.LiquibaseRunner_Subclass.onApplicationStart(Unknown Source)
    at ..infrastructure....data.LiquibaseRunner_Observer_onApplicationStart_3e5ff3fa5ec96071cea0c7faf2b64ce71ea7016d.notify(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notifyObservers(EventImpl.java:323)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:305)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.fireLifecycleEvent(ArcRecorder.java:130)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcRecorder.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent1144526294.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:108)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver class was not specified and could not be determined from the url (jdbc:otel:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findDriverClass(DatabaseFactory.java:262)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:200)
```

How can I fix this. Can some one help me?

**Edit**

Thank you very much for the comments. As said I remove the LiquibaseRunner class and without manually starting the liquibase I only used the .properties file. Now it's working.

Comment: Hi, Are you including this dependency?

`<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Anyway, on the top example you are using the reactive driver and bellow you are using plain JDBC...
They are 2 quite different setups

Comment: Do you really need? `quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost/sampledb`

Comment: And why are you starting  Liquibase manually while you have set migrate.atStart=true in your config ?

Comment: @BrunoBaptista Hi. Yes I am using  that dependency with the <dependency>quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</dependency><artifactId>io.quarkus</artifactId>. Actually thing Is not required to quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://localhost/sampledb. I want to integrate this application wtih OpenTelemetry.

Comment: @Serkan Hi. Actually thing is this application written with few other developers. Thank you very much for your comment. I will check It.

Comment: @BrunoBaptista if you can give some tip where I can find how to setup this with reactive driver or JDBC driver. Actually this current application is written in this way. It doesn't matter I can change it. Also Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Just posted an answer... Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes. Both your answers was helped me to solve this problem. The problem was as you said using two different drivers. Also, Serkan asked about why I start liquibase  manually. I checked it and I start the liquirebase only using .properties file configs. Now It's working. Thank you very much both of you.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably configure 2 different datasources in your application.

Liquibase uses a plain JDBC driver and you seem to want the reactive driver for the application. You should be able to [configure multiple datasources](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#multiple-datasources) (see link for details) in your application.

**Reactive for the app:**

To Configure the default [reactive driver for Postgres](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#reactive-postgresql-client-extension) (see link) on Quarkus you need to add this extension to maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And configure it like in this example in `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=sarah
quarkus.datasource.password=connor
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus_test
```

**JDBC for Liquibase:**

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configs including [multiple datasource configs for Liquibase](https://quarkus.io/guides/liquibase#multiple-datasources):

```
quarkus.datasource.sampledb.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.sampledb.username=sarah
quarkus.datasource.sampledb.password=connor
quarkus.datasource.sampledb.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sampledb
quarkus.liquibase.sampledb.schemas=SAMPLEDB_TEST_SCHEMA
quarkus.liquibase.sampledb.change-log=db/sampledb.xml
quarkus.liquibase.sampledb.migrate-at-start=true
```

This will allow you to configure the OpenTelemetry instrumentation according to the specificities of each datasource.