# Integrate db with OpenTelemetry in quarkus

Tags: liquibase, quarkus, open-telemetry

I am try to integrate quarkus application with OpenTelemetry. For that I want Instrumentation for JDBC. In the documentation  https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#jdbc it mentions to use https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/jdbc/library#driver-way . But bucause of the project configuration I can use this. But in the documentation there is another way. https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/jdbc/library#datasource-way  . How can I implement this solution in quarkus.

Can some one help me to this?

This is my liquibase runner file

```
package .....infrastructure.data;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

import io.quarkus.runtime.LaunchMode;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import io.quarkus.runtime.util.ExceptionUtil;
import liquibase.Contexts;
import liquibase.LabelExpression;
import liquibase.Liquibase;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseConnection;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory;
import liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.ResourceAccessor;
import io.quarkus.logging.Log;

@ApplicationScoped
public class LiquibaseRunner {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url")
    String datasourceUrl;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.username")
    String datasourceUsername;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password")
    String datasourcePassword;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.liquibase.change-log")
    String changeLogLocation;

    public void onApplicationStart(@Observes StartupEvent even) {
        LaunchMode mode = io.quarkus.runtime.LaunchMode.current();
        if(mode != LaunchMode.TEST) {
            this.runMigration();
        } else {
            Log.info("Skipping DB migrations in TEST mode.");
        }
    }
    public void runMigration() {
        Log.info("Migrating DB " + datasourceUrl);
        Liquibase liquibase = null;
        try {
            ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
            DatabaseConnection conn = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().openConnection(datasourceUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword, null, resourceAccessor);

            liquibase = new Liquibase(changeLogLocation, resourceAccessor, conn);
            liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error("Liquibase Migration Exception: " + ExceptionUtil.generateStackTrace(e));
        }
        finally {
            if(liquibase!=null)
            {
                try {
                    liquibase.close();
                } catch (LiquibaseException e) {
                    Log.info(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

     
}
```

Comment: Please check the instructions on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75481571/liquibase-error-in-quarkus-when-using-with-open-telemetry?rq=1

Comment: Also, are you using the Liquibase quarkus extenson? https://quarkus.io/guides/liquibase

Comment: Hi Bruno. Thank you very much for the comment. The link you first comment, it's working for that situation. It's also my question. But I have to keep this liquibase runner class. So, I have to move to another solution. Also, thank you very much.

Comment: On the second link, related to the Quarkus liquibase tutorial, there is an example on how to use a custom Liquibase object: https://quarkus.io/guides/liquibase#using-the-liquibase-object
This way it will be integrated with Quarkus with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you. You have to prepare your `DataSource` and then use also the `Connection` from it.

```java
public void runMigration() {
    Log.info("Migrating DB " + datasourceUrl);

    try (OpenTelemetryDataSource dataSource = dataSource();
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor = new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(Thread.currentThread()
                    .getContextClassLoader());
            DatabaseConnection conn = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
                    .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection))
                    .getConnection();
            Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(changeLogLocation, resourceAccessor, conn)) {

        liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error("Liquibase Migration Exception: " + ExceptionUtil.generateStackTrace(e));
    }
}

private OpenTelemetryDataSource dataSource() {
    // TODO return proper datasource
    final DataSource dataSource = null;
    return new OpenTelemetryDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this way i can manage it.